# Changing product's Sort By default

Tags: sort

How do I change the default by which the products are listed in the catalog? I tried from the Admin Panel but didn't work. The current default is by "Product Name" but now I want to set my own sorting option.

The new sorting option is in place (coded), it's only that I don't know how to set it as the default.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

List of options in the Admin Panel
[image]

List of options in the catalog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set the default catalog category sorting go to

Catalog > Categories > YourCategory > Display Settings

Under **Default Product Listing Sort By** uncheck Use Config Settings and then select the sort method that you want to be the default. Click Save.

To sort a category by position, select Position as the **Default Product Listing Sort By** and then scroll down and open the **Products in Category** dropdown and set the Position number on the product listings.

Comment: The options inside Default Product Listing Sort By are: Position, Product Name, Price. The options that I see in the catalog of products are: Product Name (default), Price Asc, Price Desc, Recommended (my own option), and Position desc. I suspect the actual list of options the clients see were coded, that's why they are not the same options I see in the Admin panel. I think the solution to this issue is also code. Thanks.

Comment: I'll update my answer to better respond to your new query. Let me know if that is still not what you're looking for